# Dynamic "merge_fields" for Mailchimp

Tags: javascript, json, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

For now I have the only predefined |MERGE| tag called "**POSTCODE**" in my Mailchimp list settings. For the long time users were added to this list with only this field filled, but now the task is to transform this single "**POSTCODE**" text field into array of the postcodes.

Mailchimp isn't provide array type for field in settings and fields can't be added dynamically, only manually.

The only solution I can see now is to add "**POSTCODE_1**", "**POSTCODE_2**" ... "**POSTCODE_N**" fields manually and fill them from the API calls. Or to fill this text field with postcodes merged by comma.

My question is, can we somehow do this dynamically? Add fields in case of necessity, or use an array of postcodes for single field?

Thank you.